# How to limit entity_load with entity translation module to return active language from url

Tags: i18n-l10n

Drupal 7 entity_load somehow returns all available translations when used with entity translation module. If we have 5 fields and 10 languages, there will be a total of 50 translations in result set. Is it supposed to work that way or is it too much overhead for the system?